# Extract 9 last number from a number of 14 digit

Tags: excel, vba

One of my Excel column of my board have to store numbers of 9 digits.
I'm looking for a solution to keep only the 9 **last** digits of any bigger number past in this specific column. It's only entire number.

Also if after formatting the number it appear that the number starts with 0 the 0 have to be kept. Is there another solution than adding an '0 at first ?

Here is what I already done : (i is the row number / Range01 is Range("A14:O400"))

```
If Len(Range01.Cells(i,5).value) = 9 Then
 Range01.Cells(i,5).Interior.color = vbGreen
ElseIf Len(Range01.Cells(i,5).value) = 8 Then
 Range01.Cells(i,5).value = "'0" & Range01.Cells(i,5).value
ElseIf Len(Range01.Cells(i,5).value) > 9 Then
 ????
Else
 Range01.Cells(i,5).Interior.color = vbRed
End If
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `Range01.Cells(i,5).value = CStr(Right(Range01.Cells(i,5).value, 9))`...

Comment: Is the range to be processed big? If so, I can show a piece of code able to run very fast. I mean, the range to be processed will be placed in an array and all content is dropped in less than a second and specific interior coloring will be done at once for each color...

Comment: No thanks, it's perfect like this ! (or add it as an answer of my post, thanks to that i can close the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get the last nine numbers of an integer is:

```
=MOD(A1,1000000000)
```

(For your information, that's one billion, a one with nine zeroes.)

If you're interested in showing a number with leading zeroes, you can alter the cell formatting as follows: (the format simply contains nine zeroes)

[image]

If you're interested in keeping the zeroes, you might need to use your number as a string, and precede it with a good number of repeated zeroes, something like:

```
=REPT("0",9-LEN(F8))&F8
```

- Take the length of your number (which gets automatically converted into a string)
- Subtract that from 9 (so you know how many zeroes you need)
- Create a string, consisting of that number of zeroes
- Add your number behind it, using basic concatenation.

Comment: thanks for the help, Modulus sounds an interesting solution. About the first 0 to show sadly it's not only to show it's also to keep in the number (the number is an id) so the format number is not a solution. Also I already use it to display my final number as XX.XXX.XXXX

Comment: @Xodarap: I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks, I'm making some tests

Comment: sadly it seams I got an overflow error when using modulus ... I'm using this exemple : 7000142323562 mod 1000000000

Comment: @Xodarap: I'm sorry. I can get it to work in Excel itself, but not in VBA. Do you really need VBA? I have the impression that you're doing some calculation (taking the last digits) and doing some colouring (which might be handled using conditional formatting).

Comment: @FanDuru found a VBA solution already, I think it's better for my situation. Because i think it's not possible to past a number in a cell and apply a formula into this same cell without vba, is it ?

Comment: @Xodarap: indeed. But I believe it might be better to create a new question about the overflow problem: the number you mention has no problems in Excel itself, but VBA can't handle it. I've been looking for such a question but I didn't find anything. B.t.w. I'm not FanDuru :-)

Comment: I know you're not FanDuru ^^ I just wanted to say that he had found a solution. Btw I will use it because it's perfect for my situation. like you said VBA is not able to use this kind of number. So I will let other people ask if they need about the overflow. Thanks for your help and reactivity Dominique

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the math operator of modulus. If you want the last `9` digit you can write:

```
n % 10000000000
```

Where `n` is the number in the column.
In VBA:

```
MOD(n,1000000000)
```